# Сортировка строк по возрастанию

Tags: delphi

Есть строки в `Memo1.Text` такого вида:

```
способ - 8 повторов
протащить - 2 повторов
год - 14 повторов
принять - 3 повторов
и - 15 повторов
```

Как отсортировать строки по первым словам, по длине слова - от большего к меньшему, то есть чтобы на выходе получить результат:

```
протащить - 2 повторов
принять - 3 повторов
способ - 8 повторов
год - 14 повторов
и - 15 повторов
```

Comment: Не нужно добавлять все возможные дельфийские метки, если вопрос общий и не касается особенностей версии (если дело может касаться юникода, то, наверное, стоит указывать одну из `xe`)

Comment: @MBo, В преть буду соблюдать это правило. Благодарна за подсказку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У `TStringList` (увы, не у `TStrings`) есть метод `CustomSort`. В него передаётся функция сравнения.

А внутри этой функции нужно выделить первые слова строк и сравнить их длину. В идеальном случае достаточно будет просто найти Pos пробела:

```
function SortCompare(AList: TStringList; Index1, Index2: integer): integer;
begin
  Result := Pos(' ', AList[Index2]) - Pos(' ', AList[Index1]);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button43Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sl: TStringList;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    sl.Assign(Memo1.Lines);
    sl.CustomSort(SortCompare);
    Memo1.Lines.Assign(sl);
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Оказывается решение очень простое. Обязательно изучу код что бы разобраться.